# Unable to send keys for names with certain characters

Tags: java, android, appium

Hello I have a scenario outline where I want to enter in names with the following special characters (these are paramertised under firstName)

```
Scenario Outline: Continue button is enabled for first name containing valid special characters
    Given I enter the following first name: first name: "<first name>


    Examples:

      |firstName|
      |tést     |
      |tèst     |
      |têst     |
      |tëst     |
```

Unfortunately by doing a simple send keys for these, nothing is being entered. I know if I remove the special characters, they work, I want to know how on android/appium/java to get around this so it enter these names?

```
    public void enterFirstName(String firstName) {

        signUpPage.firstNameTextField.sendKeys(firstName);
}
```

Comment: Does it behave any differently if you hardcode a string into the method rather than reading it in from your Gherkin file?

Comment: @jsheeran I can give it a go...

Comment: doesn't work even if hardcode string

Comment: found the answer which I will post soon

Answer (score 0):

It does work if hardcoded but have to make sure that the unicode keyboard is enabled.

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
signUpPage.firstNameTextField.sendKeys("tést");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```